# Google map API v3 - Add multiple infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got a **working** section of google maps javascript, I did have a problem.

Now the issue I had was that only one infowindow was showing up, the last. I found a solution on another stack thread that worked out. But I couldn't really work out why. I'm fairly new to Javascript so I was hoping someone could explain to me what changed and how.

Here is the working code:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations){
  for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var marker = locations[i];
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    var content = locations[i][0];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:latLng,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(content){
      return function(){
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
      }
    }(content));
  }
}
```

Here is the original broken code was (I'll paste only that which changed):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Now what I'd like to know if you'd be so kind, is:

1. what function does the return fn serve, and
2. what does the added `(content)` at the end of `addListener` `(}(content));)` do since as far as I can see the content has already been set within the `setContent` property.

Thank-you!

Comment: Thank-you for the edit, much easier on the eyes. Stack formatting is still a bit new to me.

Comment: You might want to change title of your question, it looks too generic.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Don't loop your `infowindow`...
You need only **one instance** of the `infowindow` **object**.
Move it **outside** of the loop, same for your functions.
Inside the loop assign its content as *relative* to the clicked `marker`

```js
const locations = [
  {lat: 45.840196, lng: 15.964331, name: "Zagreb"},
  {lat: 43.514851, lng: 16.449083, name: "Split"},
  {lat: 42.645725, lng: 18.094058, name: "Dubrovnik"},
];

function initGoogleMap(){

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Only one InfoWindow
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45, 15)
  });
  
  function placeMarker( loc ) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : new google.maps.LatLng( loc.lat, loc.lng ),
      map : map
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.close(); // Close previously opened infowindow
        infowindow.setContent(`<div id="infowindow">${loc.name}</div>`);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }
  
  // ITERATE ALL LOCATIONS. Pass every location to placeMarker
  locations.forEach( placeMarker );
  
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initGoogleMap);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0px; }
#infowindow{ padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For some reason, I had to modify marker object and access that data inside event lisener function.

Scope of click event fuction on marker is marker object.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for(int i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
    var contentString = locations[i][0];

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({           
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          contentString: contentString
    });
    marker.data = locations[i]; // adds object to marker object


    marker.addListener('click', function() {
        // read custom data in this.data   
        infowindow.setContent("<div id='infowindow'>"+ this.data[0] +"</div>");

        infowindow.open(map, this);
        map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
     });
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that. Instead, [use a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38198744/1238965).