# google maps api v3 - targeting markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I set my markers like this

```js
var
  marker,
  i,
  markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: 'img/markers/t1.png',
    id: locations[i][3]
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {

    marker.setIcon("img/serve-bracket.png");
  });
}
```

This only seems to attach the event handler on the last one. How do I add it to all markers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577417/how-to-get-all-markers-on-google-maps-v3

Comment: @YagnikDetroja in what does that link answer OP's question?

Comment: Next time, please post correct code, properly indented, and that follows [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines. With over 2500 reputation, you should be aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `addListener` in a closure.

```
var marker, i;
var markers = [];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: 'img/markers/t1.png',
        id: locations[i][3]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            marker.setIcon("img/serve-bracket.png");
        }
    })(marker, i));

    markers.push(marker);
}
```