# Have only one InfoWindow open in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to run Google Maps API v3 in an ASP.NET MVC project, and I'm trying to build a map with markers and info windows. I'd like to build the map such that only one info window at a time can be open, and its content is derived from the marker its attached to.

I've reviewed several questions on exactly this topic, but none of the solutions have worked for my project. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my failed attempt at only one open info window. Right now it renders the map and the markers, but no info windows open when I click the markers.

```
@model Project.Models.MapViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>


<div class="row">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 39.5, lng: -98.35 },
                zoom: 3
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.close();
            });

            var markers = [];



            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Addresses.Count; i++) {
                <text>
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: { lat: @Model.Addresses[i].Lat, lng: @Model.Addresses[i].Lng },
                        title: '@Model.Addresses[i].Name'
                    });

                    markers.push(marker)
                </text>
             }

            //google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            //    infoWindow.setContent(`<div id="content"> <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Test</h1> <div id="bodyContent">Test </div> </div>`);
            //    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            //});

            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++)
            {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(`<div id="content"> <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Test</h1> <div id="bodyContent">Test </div> </div>`);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>

</div>
```

Here is my working code that (non-ideally) allows multiple open info windows:

```
@model IEnumerable<Project.Models.Address>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>


<div class="row">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: { lat: 39.5, lng: -98.35 },
                zoom: 3
            });
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.close();
            });

            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                 <text>
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: { lat: @item.Lat, lng: @item.Lng },
                    title: '@item.Name'
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.setContent(`<div id="content"> <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">${@item.Name}</h1> <div id="bodyContent">${@item.Blurb}</div> </div>`);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                </text>
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>

</div>
```

Comment: 1) Why do you need the separate `for` loops? 2) Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198406/google-maps-api-v3-targeting-markers/38198744#38198744

Comment: I just tried adapting the solution there to my code, and the event listener isn't recognizing the i as the same i from the for loop

Comment: Update. It worked!